# Perform SonarQube analysis on Jenkins only if SonarQube server is online

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Following situation:

- Having a CI server like Jenkins or Hudson
- Build jobs with Maven 3 and Java projects/artifacts
- Each time a build is performed at the end a SonarQube analysis will be performed

A situation that occur, but I have no control over is, that the SonarQube server is not available. The underlying cause isn't relevant for the question. If the build tries to perform the SonarQube analysis via Maven sonar:sonar or the Jenkins SonarQube plugin as post-step the SonarQube analysis causes the build to crash or have the status failed. In my eyes the build is OK and SonarQube isn't the decisive factor.

Is there any (maven/jenkins)-plugin or possibility to avoid the analysis, **if the SonarQube server isn't available**? The SonarQube analysis of the build shall only perform if the SonarQube server is online and can perform an analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature for the moment, but maybe Jenkins has some built-in feature to run a post-job only if a specific condition is met? And in this case, you could just run a "curl" like command to check the availability of the SonarQube server to serve as a condition for the post-job to be executed?

Comment: Hi Fabrice, it is not that trivial, hence the SonarQube Server is online, but can't perform an analysis, e.g. the database is offline. Therefore you will get Response Code 200 = OK, but you can't perform an analysis.   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project foo: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'admin'@'db' (using password: YES)) ...   , but my question wasn't precise enough.